# Unique element in file - perl

Tags: perl

I want to get the unique elements (lines) from a file which I will further send through email.
I have tried 2 methods but both are not working:

1st way:

```
my @array = "/tmp/myfile.$device";
my %seen = ();
my $file = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array;
```

2nd way :

```
my $filename = "/tmp/myfile.$device";
cat $filename |sort | uniq > $file
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `sort -u $filename > $file` would do with one Unix command what you do in three commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rig the argument list, you can make Perl open the file automatically, using:

```
perl -n -e 'BEGIN{@ARGV=("/tmp/myfile.device");} print if $count{$_}++ == 0;'
```

Comment: Thanks but how to assign the above output to my file....beacuse my goal is to send file info which I have assigned to $contents vai mail... 'my $F;
die $! if(!open($F,"/tmp/myfile.device"));
my @array = <$F>;
my %seen = ();
my $file = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array;

$logger->debug("$logid >> file details: $file");

open my $ifh, '<', $file
  or die "Cannot open '$file' for reading: $!";
local $/ = '';
my $contents = <$ifh>;
close( $ifh );`
$smtp->datasend(" $contents\n\n\n");

Comment: The command prints to standard output; run `perl script > file` to get it to a file.  Or open the file in the script (BEGIN clause: `open my $h, '>', "file" or die;`) and revise the `print` to reference the file handle: `print $fh $_;` (I'd not risk omitting the `$_` in this notation, though it might work correctly.  Note the absence of a comma between `$fh` and `$_`.)  There might be a scope issue with `$fh`, in which case, you'll need to do a bit more work. Basically, the script I proposed is a bit of cheat, and would be better as part of a shell script than as part of a bigger Perl program.

Comment: The reason it's a cheat is because of the `-n` option which creates a loop around the `print` statement (the non-BEGIN part of the code) that reads lines automatically from the argument list, but doesn't print them automatically (`-p` would print automatically).  If the overall program flow doesn't fit this structure, then this suggestion isn't all that helpful.  (And even in a shell script, using `sort -u` would probably be better than using a Perl script for 'the same job'.)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have forgotten to read the file!

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file_name)
   or die("Can't open \"$file_name\": $!\n");

my %seen;
my @unique = grep !$seen{$_}++, <$fh>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file and read it.

"cat" is a shell command not perl

Try something like this

```
my $F;
die $! if(!open($F,"/tmp/myfile.$device"));
my @array = <$F>;
my %seen = (); my $file = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array;
```

The `die $!` will stop the program with an error if the file doesn't open correctly; 
`@array=<$F>` reads all the data from the file `$F` opened above into the array.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I tried but when I print the output of file its showing value 2 instead of device names.... `my $F;
die $! if(!open($F,"/tmp/myfile.$device"));
my @array = <$F>;
my %seen = ();
my $file = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array;

$logger->debug("$logid >> file details: $file");`
Output should be like Devicename 1 Devicename 2 ....